# Storing Image on Android SDCard & Path URL in SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm currently storing the photos like so in the SharedPreferences after it's captured using ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent:

```
 if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_TWO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            mImageTwo.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);


            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

            String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

            SharedPreferences shre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = shre.edit();
            edit.putString("image_two", encodedImage);
            edit.commit();
        }
```

Instead I'd like to store this image to the SD card and the url to the file path in shared preferences, so that I can load the images using the filepath and I'm able to attach these photos with the ACTION_SEND intent. It appears I can't do that with the way I'm currently storing the images.

Comment: "It appears I can't do that with the way I'm currently storing the images" -- why do you say that? Replace your `ByteArrayOutputStream` with a `FileOutputStream` pointing to a location on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). You will not be able to write to the SD card itself ([removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html)) directly, particularly on Android 4.4 and higher.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. As far as I'm concerned the only way I'm currently "storing it" now is by simply writing it to a string that can be decoded again. From what I've researched I'd need to have this image stored somewhere to be able to pass in the path to the file.

Answer (score 1):

This will return file name of saved image in sdcard so now you can save it in `shared preferences` or you can modify as you need.

```
    public static String saveImage(Bitmap imageBitmap) {

    File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(sdCardDirectory + "/Folder_Name");
    dir.mkdir();

    String fileName = "image" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpeg";
    File image = new File(dir, fileName);
    fileName = image.getPath();

    FileOutputStream outStream;
    try {

        outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);

        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        fileName = Constants.ERROR_IMAGE_SAVING;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        fileName = Constants.ERROR_IMAGE_SAVING;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return fileName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is solution:

```
public static String saveEncodedImage(String folderName, String imgFileName, String encodedImage) {
    //check sdcard is available
    String sdStatus = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if(!sdStatus.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
        // sdcard not avaliable
        return "";
    }
    String urlToPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            + File.separator
            + folderName;
    File folder = new File(urlToPath);
    if (!folder.exists()){
        folder.mkdir();
    }
    urlToPath = urlToPath + File.separator + imgFileName;
    File imgFile = new File(urlToPath);
    try {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(imgFile));
        bufferedWriter.write(encodedImage);
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
    return urlToPath;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_TWO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            mImageTwo.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

            String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
            //save to sdcard
            String urlToImage = saveEncodedImage("images","image_two",encodedImage);
            SharedPreferences shre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = shre.edit();
            edit.putString("image_two", urlToImage);
            edit.commit();
        }
```